# schema.org: Multiple opening hours on same day

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I'm building a website for a small store and want to implement schema.org-microdata-markup. The "problem": The store is opened from Tuesday till Friday – from 10:00 till 14:00 **AND** from 16:30 till 23:00 on these days. So I implemented the opening hours like this…

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu-Fr 10:00-14:00, 16:00-23:00">XYZ</time>
```

But this way, the HTML-validator says…

> Bad value Tu-Fr 10:00-14:00, 16:00-23:00 for attribute datetime on element time: The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format.

How can I implement these multiple opening hours a day? Or is it impossible to do this with the `<time>`-tag and I have to change it to `<meta>`-tags? Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: (Contains) same questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8918284/1591669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the notations schema.org uses for openingHours are just not (yet) valid by the [HTML5 spec for the time element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element).

You can copy all the examples from [LocalBusiness](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) in the [Validator](http://validator.nu) and they will all fail validation.

Until the spec contains a definition to write openingHours in a time element you will have to ignore the HTML validators I'm afraid.

BTW. The text on the schema.org site implies you *could* defines multiple times in one value:

> The opening hours for a business. Opening hours can be specified as a weekly time range, starting with days, then **times per day**.

Answer (score 3):

What if you used 2 entries for openingHours?

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu-Fr 10:00-14:00">XYZ</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu-Fr 16:00-23:00">XYZ</time>
```

Comment: Thought the same. Maybe first one will be overwritten by last and thus only show 16:00-23:00, on which case you'd be better off by combining both: 10:00-23:00.

Answer (score 2):

The [LocalBusiness](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) example has been updated to use `<meta>` elements:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
  <span itemprop="name">GreatFood</span>
  ...
  Hours:
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">Mon-Sat 11am - 2:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Th 17:00-21:30">Mon-Thu 5pm - 9:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00">Fri-Sat 5pm - 10:00pm
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran in to the same issue and found that the second string of hours needs to be on another line like this:

```
<p><time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,Tu,We,Th, 08:30-13:30">M-Th 8:30am-12:30pm & 1:30pm-6:00pm</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,Tu,We,Th, 14:30-18:00"></time></p>
```

It's also important to keep this code inside the closing  tag, otherwise it will not register as being formatted correctly.