# Different (type of) openinghours per day using schema.org

Tags: microdata

I use microdata and specifically the LocalBusiness schema on my site.
I was also reading this: [schema.org: Multiple opening hours on same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926650/schema-org-multiple-opening-hours-on-same-day)

But what I want is to define per day what the opening hours are, since they may vary a lot.

What I currently see in other examples is:

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu-Fr 10:00-14:00">XYZ</time>
```

Can I also use either of these options?

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu 10:00-14:00">XYZ</time>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Fr 11:00-14:00">XYZ</time>
```

or this

```
<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Tu 10:00-14:00">XYZ
<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="FR 11:00-14:00">XYZ
```

And not only that, on some days a business might be only open by appointment.
How to specify that? I'm assuming when I leave a day out in my <time> specification it will be interpreted as closed, but by appointment I don't know.

** UPDATE **

I now have this:

```
<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
<link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday">
<time datetime="07:00">07:00</time> - <time datetime="01:00">01:00</time>
</div>
```

with Google rich snippet tool I now see

Item 
  type: http://schema.org/localbusiness
  property:
  name: Syriana
  description:
  address:  Item 1
  openinghoursspecification:      Item 2
  openinghoursspecification:      Item 3

Item 2
  type: http://schema.org/openinghoursspecification
  property:
  dayofweek:    http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday

I see the day, but not the time in the rich snippet tool...why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [LocalBusiness](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) example has been updated and shows an example of multiple times for a span of days.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
  <span itemprop="name">GreatFood</span>
  ...
  Hours:
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">Mon-Sat 11am - 2:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Th 17:00-21:30">Mon-Thu 5pm - 9:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00">Fri-Sat 5pm - 10:00pm
</div>
```

More from the description of `openingHours`:

> The opening hours for a business. Opening hours can be specified as a weekly time range, starting with days, then times per day. Multiple days can be listed with commas ',' separating each day. Day or time ranges are specified using a hyphen '-'.
>
> - Days are specified using the following two-letter combinations: Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su.
> - Times are specified using 24:00 time. For example, 3pm is specified as 15:00.
> - Here is an example: Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm.
> - If a business is open 7 days a week, then it can be specified as Monday through Sunday, all day.

Although the `openingHours` description uses the time element with the datetime attribute, the weekly time range is not a valid value, so using a meta element may be preferable.

In addition, all Item-Types that derive from [Place](http://schema.org/Place) also have an [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) property.  It is much more wordy than the `openingHours` property.  This cane be used somewhat like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
  <span itemprop="name">GreatFood</span>
  ...
  Hours:
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Lunch Hours">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Wednesday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Thursday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Friday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Saturday">

    Mon-Sat
    <time itemprop="opens" datetime="11:00">11am</time> -
    <time itemprop="closes" datetime="14:30">2:30pm</time>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Supper Hours">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Wednesday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Thursday">

    Mon-Thu
    <time itemprop="opens" datetime="17:00">5pm</time> -
    <time itemprop="closes" datetime="21:30">9:30pm</time>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Weekend Supper Hours">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Friday">
    <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Saturday">

    Fri-Sat
    <time itemprop="opens" datetime="17:00">5pm</time> -
    <time itemprop="closes" datetime="22:00">10:00pm</time>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. And what if it's the same day? E.g. Monday is "Mo-Mo 9:00-14:30"? And also what if it's open by appointment only can that be specified?

Comment: No need to thank me, that's what the upvotes are for. For Monday, just do "Mo 09:00-14:30". I updated my answer.

Comment: If you want to specify that a certain time range is open by appointment, then use the openingHoursSpecification and in its description, state that those particular hours are by-appointment.

Comment: From your answer I derive that for each day that has different openinghours I need to created a new element <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification"> which contains link elements of the days that have the same openinghours?
And is the text "Mon-Sat" in your answer required for correct working? Or will just the link elements be enough?

Comment: No, the text Mon-Sat is not necessary since it it not an itemProp.

Comment: I made a mistake on my example. All of the time elements should have an itemprop. I'm fixing it now.

Comment: I did now and updated my answer..I don't see the times in the rich snippet test tool

Comment: The rich snippet tool may not actually show those times. There other microdata checkers out there, though.

Comment: It does show times with your latest code update, so all is good now :)

Comment: @Floran, do you have a link? http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.toptrouwen.nl%2Ftrouwlocaties%2F380%2Fsyriana does not show the times.

Comment: It does for me...all the way at the bottom:
Item 2
type: http://schema.org/openinghoursspecification
property: 
dayofweek: http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday
opens: 07:00
closes: 01:00